# Share a folder NOT in the home directory

Tags: permissions, windows, hard-drive, nautilus, sharing

This post has been up for six days now with no answer. Obviously this sharing can be done and I know I am missing something obvious but what?

Do I set the share only in Samba and not use the Nautilus GUI?  I have tried it both ways with no luck.

I can easily make a share in my home directory using the Nautilus GUI. Can read and write from Windows.

The permissions on the shared folder have been set to both 775 and 777 with no success.

I have checked and the samba users match the Ubuntu users - the users were migrated to samba.

I want to set up a password protected folder,  but at this point I am just looking to get the share working.

I've spent hours working on this which has gotten me more familiar with the Ubuntu but no closer to solving this problem.

---

I am trying to share a folder outside the home directory.

Server runs Ubuntu 16, client= Win7

I can easily share folders in my Home directory.

I have added and removed Samba and then re-added it from the Nautilus screen

The folder Owner is me, the Group is `sambashare`. Permissions are `drwxrwxr-x`

Folder should be shared with everyone according to the Local Network Share settings.  I have created Samba users and passwords without any luck. Folder was created as root on second hard drive (named M1) and then a folder recreated below that called Data. The Data folder has been shared as above.

Windows machine is currently saying "no permission" to access folder.

Comment: Can you post your smb.conf? I've not experienced this problem when using the actual samba package

Answer (score 0):

## How to share any folder LOCATED OUTSIDE the "HOME" folder.

To share a folder inside the "HOME" folder you simply use the system filemanager (NAUTILUS) share menu option, but if the folder is OUTSIDE the "HOME" folder (and maybe even in other partition) you must configure with a script.

---

Example. If you want to have a share with the following properties:

```
    ShareNAME: "myShareName"
     PathNAME: "/media/myUserName/myPartitionName/mySharedFolder"
         User: "myUserName"
 Guest Access is "ENABLED" (password not required)
```

Then do the following to setup share:

1.- Open file: ***/etc/samba/smb.conf*** with a text editor (GEDIT) in ROOT mode.

2.- Append at the end (and save) the following:

```
[myShareName]
   path = /media/myUserName/myPartitionName/mySharedFolder
   read only = no
   force user = myUserName
   guest ok = yes
```

3.- Restart SMB running (in bash): **sudo service smbd restart**

4.- Check **smb.conf** for internal correctness running in bash "testparm".

---

**References:**

- [Share Folders using Samba in Home Network with Mint 21](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=377372)
- [Setting up Samba as a Standalone Server](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server)